# How can I cluster two machines to double the processing power?

Tags: networking

If I had two computers running ubuntu server (or just one) could I "hook" the two machines together to double processing power?  How would that work?

Comment: Depends a lot what this is for.. Web servers? DB servers? Heavy computing? Continuous Integration? Other?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sounds like you want to cluster them to make the most of the processing power. Awesome idea! I would take a look at:

- [UbuntuClusters](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuClusters) (Ubuntu wiki)
- [EasyUbuntuClustering](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/EasyUbuntuClustering) (Ubuntu wiki)
- [Building a Beowulf Cluster in just 13 steps](https://www.linux.com/tutorials/building-beowulf-cluster-just-13-steps/) (linux.com)

Happy hacking!