# How to turn a local network of Ubuntu computers into effectively one computer controlled by a single 'master´ computer on the same network?

Tags: networking

How to turn a local network of Ubuntu computers into effectively one computer controlled by a single 'master´ computer on the same network?

I think the question is clear. To clarify, I would like to be able to have computers on my LAN contribute to computing tasks run from my 'main' machine.

For example, if I am video editing on the 'main' machine, the OS should send other jobs to the LAN computers to execute, and all this automatically, as if it were one machine.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what you want to do is taking advantage of the processing power of multi computer (with 2 or more available machines running within the same local network) and that way increasing performance, if so, you might want to cluster them.

A very good answer was provided here with a few tool options that are available: [How can I cluster two machines to double the processing power?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57526/how-can-i-cluster-two-machines-to-double-the-processing-power)

Comment: Nice :) Thank you, you have understood quite clearly what I wish to do. I will check out the suggested procedure ...

Comment: @David Rather than spending your time editing my text to no real purpose, you might have tried to answer my question, especially given your apparent credentials. What is posted as an answer is outdated and therefore my question should stand and be answered by someone who is knowledgeablee and current.

Comment: @debonaire57 No problem, happy to help. Hmm, not sure why your question got re-edited. In any case, if the linked procedure doesn't work for you, I'm sure there is an updated cluster procedure somewhere, I read a bit more about it here: https://www.linuxjournal.com/magazine/building-linux-based-high-performance-compute-cluster

Comment: Also, as a fun project, you could make a simple dispatcher on your favorite programming language and send out tasks to a different machine on the network depending on CPU usage (many problems here, for example, the entire task would need to be sent, not sub-processes unless we're developing in kernel... but fun nevertheless :) ).

Comment: Thanks one more, I read the article and realized that there is after all an ambiguity in my question. I do not necessarily want to build a parallel computing cluster, this would mean using or writing parallel programs. What I want is that my main desktop when running low on resources will allocate a task/Prgm automatically to one of the computers on the LAN. If the solution also entails that the cluster can do real parallel program execution, then great.